# Kernel of Nilpotent Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space with $n=\dim V=10$ and $N∈L(V)$ is nilpotent. What are possible values for $\dim\ker(N^3)-\dim\ker(N)$? The only two things I know that are helpful to this that $\ker(N)\subseteq\ker(N^2)\subseteq\ldots\subseteq\ker(N^n)$ and $N^n=0$ for $N$ nilpotent. But it seems that all values between $1$ and $9$ are possible just by looking at these two restrictions. Can anyone give a hint? Thanks.

Comment: In your chain of kernels, it is not only that each is contained in the next, but also the increase in dimension at each step cannot increase. Which is to say, if $\ker(N^{k-1})$  has dimension $x$, and $\ker(N^k)$ has dimension $x+y$, then $\ker(N^{k+1})$ has dimension at most $x+2y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $k_1, \ldots, k_m \ge 1$ are the sizes of the Jordan blocks of $N$, then $\dim \ker(N^3) = \sum_{i=1}^m \min\{1, k_i\} = \sum_{i=1}^m 1 = m$ and $\dim \ker(N) = \sum_{i=1}^m \min\{3, k_i\}$. Thus the difference is
\begin{align}
\dim \ker (N^3) - \dim \ker (N)
&= \sum_{i=1}^m (\min\{3, k_i\} - 1)
\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m \min\{2, k_i - 1\}
\\
&= 2\cdot \#\{i : k_i \ge 3\} + \#\{i : k_i = 2\}.
\end{align}
Finally, we have the restriction $\sum_{i=1}^m k_i = 10$.

This limits what $\dim \ker (N^3) - \dim \ker (N)$ can be. For instance, the largest this quantity can be is $6$ (when the Jordan blocks have sizes $3,3,3,1$ or $3,3,2,2$).

Answer (score 0):

Take the matrix $N$ with only entries of $0$, but $N_{1i}=1$ for $i>j$ with $0<j\leq 10$. We have $\operatorname{rk}(N)=10-j$ and $\operatorname{rk}(N^3)=0$ since $N^2=0$. Using the rank-nullity-theorem, we have:
\begin{equation}
\dim\ker(N^3)-\dim\ker(N)
=\operatorname{rk}(N)-\operatorname{rk}(N^3)
=10-j.
\end{equation}
Therefore every value between $0$ and $9$ is possible.

Comment: Your matrix $N$ has rank $1$ since there is only one distinct nonzero column.

Comment: Damn, you're right! I already had a strong feeling to oversee something obvious, but didn't find anything. Guess it was just a bit too obvious. Thanks!