# Why the increase of dimension of null space is nonincreasing

Tags: linear-algebra

It's true that the null space of an operator will increase as the operator increase it's degree $$\text{null}\  T^0 \subset\text{null}\  T \subset \text{null}\  T^2 \subset\text{null}\  T^3 \subset \cdots$$

But why the increase of this null space can't be increasing? That is to say if from $\text{null}\  T^0 $ to the $\text{null}\  T $, the increase of dimension is $k$, then from $\text{null}\  T $ to $\text{null}\  T^2 $, the increase of dimension must be less or equal to $k$. Also for $T^3,..., T^n,..$ Any help on proving this? Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the Jordan form of the matrix of $T$, focusing on how the Jordan blocks corresponding to eigenvalue $0$ behave when taking powers of $T$ will explain this.

Comment: The context of OP's question is from Arthur's comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4424668/kernel-of-nilpotent-operator#comment9259401_4424668).

Answer (score 2):

Let $k\ge1$. If $x\in\mathop{\rm null}T^{k+1}$ then $T(x)\in \mathop{\rm null}T^{k}$; therefore, we may view $T$ as a map $\mathop{\rm null}T^{k+1} \to \mathop{\rm null}T^k$. Moreover, $T(x)\in\mathop{\rm null}T^{k-1}$ if and only if $x\in \mathop{\rm null}T^k$. This means that $T$ induces an injective linear map $\mathop{\rm null}T^{k+1}/\mathop{\rm null}T^k \to \mathop{\rm null}T^k / \mathop{\rm null}T^{k-1}$.
Hence,
$$
\dim (\mathop{\rm null}T^{k+1}) - \dim(\mathop{\rm null}T^k)
= 
\dim (\mathop{\rm null}T^{k+1}/\mathop{\rm null}T^k) 
\\\le
\dim (\mathop{\rm null}T^k / \mathop{\rm null}T^{k-1})
=
\dim (\mathop{\rm null}T^k) - \dim(\mathop{\rm null}T^{k-1}),$$
which is what you wanted to prove.